# MediaElement won't play an mp3

Tags: c#, wpf, mp3, mediaelement

In the xaml I have:

```
<Page.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/TheseusAndTheMinotaur;component/Images/marbleBackground.jpg"/>
</Page.Background>
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Margin="0" IsHitTestVisible="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="500" x:Name="gameArea"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <MediaElement x:Name="footStep" Source="minotaurFoot.mp3" Volume="1" LoadedBehavior="Manual"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnExit" Content="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,220,20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="btnExit_Click" Grid.Column="2" IsHitTestVisible="True"/>
        <Canvas x:Name="pbxMap" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Background="#7F000000" IsHitTestVisible="True" Focusable="True"/>
    </Grid>
```

In a method that fires I have:

```
this.myGamePlayerPage.footStep.Play();
```

No sound plays but there is no error. Any ideas why this is? Thanks.

**EDIT:** I changed the source to this: `Source="C:\newnew\TheseusAndTheMinotaur\minotaurFoot.mp3"` and it works. But this is no good. It won't work for other ocmputers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setup seems to be correct, but i guess that the `MediaElement` cannot find the `minotaurFoot.mp3`. Register the `MediaFailed`-Event of the `MediaElement` and check if it gets raised. The `ExceptionRoutedEventArgs` passed to the method, should contain information about, why the file cannot be played.

**XAML**

```
<MediaElement x:Name="footStep" 
              MediaFailed="MediaFailedHandler"
              Source="minotaurFoot.mp3"
              Volume="1"
              LoadedBehavior="Manual"/>
```

**C#**

```
public void MediaFailedHandler(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e){
    // e.ErrorException contains information what went wrong when playing your mp3
}
```

**Update**

You also need to copy the mp3 to the output folder of you project. This is done by setting `Copy always` or `Copy if newer` in the Advanced Setting `Copy to Output directory`.

Select the mp3 file in your project, right click to open ContextMenu. Then select Properties and make the specified setting above.

Comment: Thanks! It says it cannot find the media file. I have my file directly in the project. With images this location works. Is this an issue for mp3?

Comment: @user2602079 no there is no issue with mp3 files. you only need to change the Source property of the MediaElement. Try using this `/TheseusAndTheMinotaur;component/minotaurFoot.mp3`. Or use the PropertyWindow of Visual Studio to set the Source

Comment: No such luck. I also put it in the Images folder and gave the same file path as my images and no luck. Thanks though.

Comment: May be worth noting that the mediaElement is in a grid, and when i call it in code, i do not specify the grid, only the page. This is because the grid doesn't seem to have it in intellisense but the page does.

Comment: Thank you. Working nicely. One last thing - mediaElement seems to need windows media player on the client machine. This seems pretty bad, as some machines might not have it. Is there an alternative that I can trust more to play on other peoples computers?

Comment: @user2602079 I´m not sure. You can read more about MediaElemenet [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa970915(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I am in Windows 11, I installed Windows Media Player Version 11.2203.30.0 from the play store and it still won't play any audio.  The error is the same on startup of the above sample code I get e.ErrorException = {"Windows Media Player version 10 or later is required."}, same error if my button invokes .play() I am specifying this.MediaElement.Source = new Uri(@"S:\_PUB1\_CLIPARTS\COW_OK.wav", UriKind.Absolute);  Same results with .mp3   backslashes are all in there, SO messing up again.