# Playing sounds with button on Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I try to build app on Windows Phone 8 and try to create 9 buttons as images that trigger sound after clicking on them. I can successfully create one button but when I extend my code to create 8 new buttons some sounds do not play. How to fix this to make all sounds play.
My code for one button that I multiply 9 times.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<!--3x3 Grid -->
<Grid x:Name="Column" Grid.Row="0">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="*" />
   <RowDefinition Height="*" />
   <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <!-- First Sound -->
<Button x:Name="FirstButton"
        Style="{StaticResource FirstButtonStyle}"
        Click="FirstButton_Click" />

        <MediaElement x:Name="FirstSound"
                      Source="/Assets/sounds/first.mp3"
                      Volume="1"
                      AutoPlay="False" />
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
private void FirstButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FirstSound.Play();
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Style x:Key="FirstButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
           <Image x:Name="FirsButtonImage" Source="/Assets/images/firstimage.png"/>
       </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: "some sounds do not play" is pretty vague. Presumably some copies are not so good as the rest.

Comment: All audio files are ok. I can play only first 5 sounds.

Comment: Your question is really vague!! Are all the sounds the same format? (i.e all mp3s or other formats), you need to elaborate what you mean by "some sounds don't play" ? Do you do anything to interrupt the player?

Comment: Yes, all the files are in mp3 format. I can play only first 5 audio files.

Comment: I do not interrupt the player. It is simple app that have 9 buttons-images that play two second mp3 files as buttons are clicked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MediaElement won't play an mp3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260001/mediaelement-wont-play-an-mp3)